# ASP.NET Identity + Bearer Token + Multi-Tenant

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I've created a multi-tenant application using Entity Framework, WebAPI, ASP.NET Identity. Basically it reads the subdomain of the tenant and using it to read the connection string from the database and sets it on runtime.

Everything is great, database is creating etc, but the only issue now is the ASP.NET Identity Bearer Token.

When I've generated a bearer access token for http://tenant1.#####.com/token, it seems that the token is signed on the same application (no machine key was specified) and it's allowing access to http://tenant2.#####.com controllers as well, which shouldn't be the case as it's different subdomains / tenants.

Are there any ways around this? Or perhaps I should be looking into other Security Framework and not ASP.NET Identity?

Comment: You need to take control over tokens and add a custom data there, the tenant name. Since tokens are based on claims this should be possible. Then have another check upon each request to verify if the current tenant matches the one from the token. This check could be done in a custom http module for example.

Comment: Hello, in this scenario would using claims be a "safe" approach? Because all it takes is to be able to spoof a token with the correct tenantid claim and the request may go through?

Comment: You can't spoof a token at the client side.

Comment: @WiktorZychla your solution works, appreciate it

Answer (score 3):

MVC5 makes it easy to add a tenant name claim to the user identity.
In the Models directory, edit the `ApplicationUser` class in `IdentityModels.cs`:

```
public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
{
    // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
    var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

    // Add claim for tenant name
    userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("tenantName", "abcCompany");

    // Add custom user claims here
    return userIdentity;
}
```

Then when an authenticated request is processed, validate that the User contains correct claim and value.

Comment: Is it possible to get an example of how to acquire the tenant name at the point where you're adding it as a claim? Currently looking into this but also trying to avoid overriding everything within SignInManager.

Comment: I am doing something similar to how the user

Comment: It depends on your implementation. The tenant name may be based on the sub-domain of the request, a cookie value, or it could be explicitly provided by the user.  As for accessing the value, I am using the same pattern ASP.NET uses to implement IPrincipal and IIdentity.  Internally, IPrincipal has a per-request reference to the current user.